# Combine two small functions into one

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to "write a function Single() that takes a number and returns the number of times you must multiply the digits in num so as to reach a single digit. e.g. Single(456)//4*5*6=120, 1*2*0=0//it takes two loops to to reach the single digit so the return would be 2.

My problem is that now I have to put in an array of individual digits instead of a number. So I probably need to combine the two functions.

```js
function numberToArray(num) {
  var tmpString = num.toString();
  var tempArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpString.length; i++) {
    tempArray.push(tmpString[i]);
  }
  return tempArray;
}

function reachSingle(tempArray) {
  var count = 0;
  var k = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    k *= tempArray[i];
  }
  count++;
  if (k <= 10) return count;
  else {
    var newArray = numberToArray(k);
    return count + reachSingle(newArray);
  }
}

document.write(reachSingle([2, 9, 3, 7, 6]));
```

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I want to have only one function that takes a number instead of an array as input and can return the result of second function

Comment: I think this question is against stackoverflow’s rule

Comment: @Kai In what way?

Comment: it looks like an exercise, homework :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach with an exit condition for numbers smaller than 10 and return in this case zero. Otherwise return one plus the result of the call of the product of the digits.

```js
function reachSingle(n) {
    if (n < 10) return 0;
    return 1 + reachSingle(Array.from(n.toString()).reduce((a, b) => a * b));
}


console.log(reachSingle(29376)); // 4
```